# Proving that something is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $m,n \in \Bbb N$ prove that if $gcd(m,n)>1$ then $\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n$ is not cyclic.

My solution attempt :I know that if $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n$ is cyclic so how would i use this to prove that if it is $>1$ then it is not cyclic?

Comment: so we would try this to show a contradiction?

Comment: @lhf Yes you are right, I was trying to reduce to  $\Bbb Z_g\times\Bbb Z_g= \Bbb Z_{g^2}$ where $g = gcd(n,m)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(m,n) >1$ then $L:=\text{lcm}(m,n) = \dfrac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)} < mn$.

Since $m\mid L$ and $n\mid L$ then $L(x,y) = (Lx,Ly) = (0,0)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$. Therefore there's no element of degree $mn$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Let $l=lcm(m,n)$. Then $la=0$ for all $a \in \Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n$.